# Line search fails when training linear SVM with caret

Tags: performance, error-handling, svm, text-mining, r-caret

I am trying to train a linear SVM while tuning the parameters with 10fold CV for binary text classification.
As all solutions provided in other threads do not work and I already removed all NAs, NANs and Inf and balanced my dataset by applying downsampling but still the model returns NAs and fails in line search. Therefore I need the help of the community as I am kind of stuck.

The data has 2099 observations of 926 variables and is mostly 0 and 1, 2 or 3s.

dat_SetimentAnalysis <- c(

This is my code:

```
set.seed(335)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(dat_SentimentAnalysis$Usefulness, p = .75, 
                                  list = FALSE, 
                                  times = 1)
train <- dat_SentimentAnalysis[ trainIndex,]
test  <- dat_SentimentAnalysis[-trainIndex,]


#check for distribution of class
table(train$Usefulness) 

#downsample training set
train <- downSample(train, as.factor(train$Usefulness))

#check again for distribution
table(train$Usefulness) 

train <- na.omit(train) #no na values detected

#separate feature and predictors

x_train <- train[2:926]
y_train <- as.factor(train$Usefulness)

x_test <- test[2:926]
y_test <- as.factor(test$Usefulness)

sum(is.na(x_train))
sum(is.na(y_train))


#tune hyperparameters for SVM


fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                           number = 10,
                           repeats = 3,
                           search = "grid",
                           classProbs = TRUE, 
                           savePredictions = TRUE)




model    <- caret::train(x = x_train,
                 y = y_train,
                 method = "svmLinear",
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 tunegrid=data.frame(C=c(0.25, 0.5, 1,5,8,12,100)))
```

Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong? Because, when I do not perform tuning I get a very poor performing SVM with around 52 % accuracy but at least I get one. So maybe something with the tuning formula is wrong?

Thank you very much for your help!